# Natural language processing: finding semantic similarities with standard algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, semantics

I want to ask if there exists some (collection of) standard algorithms (standard in the sense like the Simplex algorithm for linear optimization) which are scientifically accepted and practically "good enough" to sort and rate short (one to three sentences) questions with respect to their similarity. That means that I want some measure to tell that from the following three questions:

1. "Has the weight of Paul's dog increased over the last week?"
2. "Is the dog heavier than before?"
3. "Has Paul a dog named Lucifer?"

the first two share the highest common semantic. I know that this is quite a hard problem and I think that any solution down the range towards simple comparison will also serve (failing on the given example, but oh well), my question is, what is current (open source) standard?

Comment: There are algorithms (almost exclusively in research publications) that attempt to do this. There is nothing that will always do this with a 100% accuracy, however. If you are up for experimenting yourself, look into some of the recent papers on *paraphrasing*. The [ACL anthology](http://aclweb.org/anthology/) is a good place to search for such publications.

Comment: http://deeptutor2.memphis.edu/Semilar-Web/public/demo.jsp
This tool gives the demo for some of the algorithms. Try it out. I did  not try the tool. So U can try. Thankz :)

Comment: @Gunjan I tried several algorithms on that page you named and they all failed on my three questions (not a single one stating that the semantic of  1 & 2 is more akin to one another than to 3). Seems that either I expect the wrong things or this is quite beyond what currently is possible with the used approaches.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I had looked at several semantic similarity algorithms myself. But none seems to work that good. So it might be the second thing that it is beyond currently used approaches. But you should keep  looking. There can be something which we missed out

Comment: Another project: http://www.semantic-measures-library.org/sml/index.php